# Permission denied when starting spark Command line on AWS EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr

I have launched a cluster with 2 machines (1 master, 1 core) on AWS EMR service with 1 keypairs.

then logged into master instance with ssh provided the created .pem

successed!

then I try to run spark-shell or pyspark on master instance and get the following error

```
Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied:   user=ec2-user, access=WRITE, inode="/user":hdfs:hadoop:drwxr-xr-x
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkFsPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:271)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:257)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:238)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:179)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6512)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6494)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkAncestorAccess(FSNamesystem.java:6446)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInternal(FSNamesystem.java:4248)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInt(FSNamesystem.java:4218)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:4191)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:813)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:600)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:635)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)
```

Comment: Answering your own post should be done with an answer, not edit. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Comment: @timss thanks , done

Comment: Since your answer correctly addresses the problem, you should consider accepting it, so that others with a similar problem can benefit of it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

solved by myself.

ssh with ec2-user would success in logging in, but cause permission error when starting spark

ssh with user hadoop solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue you don't have to always ssh as the hadoop user. The shell is trying to access the current users home directory on HDFS.

Running the following terminal commands as the hadoop user (e.g. with `su`) then allowed me to use spark-shell as my normal user

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/myuser
hdfs dfs -chown myuser:hadoop /user/myuser
```

(Replace `myuser` with the user you want to run the shell as)